# iOS transfer app from ad hoc to Enterprise on another account

Tags: ios, enterprise, transfer, account

I've created an app for a friend's company. Up until now, I've been using ad hoc distribution, but now the company has signed up for an Enterprise account. What is the process for them to be able to distribute the app to their employees using their Enterprise account? Do I just send them the project file? Then what would they have to do on their end? I remember when I created the app, the certificates and profiles and crap was all very confusing, especially involving push notification service. Will they have to redo all of that stuff? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to set up appID and Provisioning Profiles in the Enterprise Account - since WWDC 2015 APNs is available for Enterprise as well.
Make sure to change the bundle identifier as well.
Next you have to adjust your project settings to reflect the changes.

You could as well add a new target in your project and set it up with the new settings and keep the original target with your old settings, this way you can build for both setups